# Calendar Printer - how to return each new line

Tags: java, printing, calendar

I'm trying to print out a calendar for an entire year given any year. The code starts each month on the correct day, but continues to count out seven number and returns the next line to the same starting column. How might I correct this?

Here is my current output:

```
           2017

          January
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
  1       2           3               4                   5                           6                            7 
  8       9          10              11                  12                          13                          14 
 15      16          17              18                  19                          20                          21 
 22      23          24              25                  26                          27                          28 
 29      30          31 
          February
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
              1                   2                       3                               4   5       6           7 
              8                   9                      10                              11  12      13          14 
             15                  16                      17                              18  19      20          21 
             22                  23                      24                              25  26      27          28
```

And continues on for the year. I believe the error is in the printCalendar method but I don't know what to do.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class CalendarPrinter{

  public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Calendar Printer\n");
    System.out.print("Enter the year? ");
    int year = kbd.nextInt();

    printCalendar(year);

    System.out.println("\n" + year + ".txt generated.");
}

public static void printCalendar(int year) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(year + ".txt");
    outputFile.println("           " + year);

    for(int month = 1; month <=12; month++) {
        outputFile.println("\n          " + getMonthName(month));
        outputFile.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
        int numDays = getNumberofDays(month, year);

        for(int day = 1; day <= numDays; day++){
            int dayWeek = getDayofTheWeek(day, month, year);
            for(int k = 0; k < dayWeek; k++)
                outputFile.print("    ");
            outputFile.printf("%3d ", day);
            if(day % 7 == 0) {
                outputFile.println("");
                dayWeek = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    outputFile.close();
 }

 public static String getMonthName(int month){

    String name;
    switch(month){
    case 1: name = "January";
    break;
    case 2: name = "February";
    break;
    case 3: name = "March";
    break;
    case 4: name = "April";
    break;
    case 5: name = "May";
    break;
    case 6: name = "June";
    break;
    case 7: name = "July";
    break;
    case 8: name = "August";
    break;
    case 9: name = "September";
    break;
    case 10: name = "October";
    break;
    case 11: name = "November";
    break;
    case 12: name = "December";
    break;
    default: name = "Unknown";
    break;
    }
    return name;
  }//method

 public static int getNumberofDays(int month, int year){

    int numDays;
    switch(month){
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
        numDays = 31;
        break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        numDays = 30;
        break;
    case 2:
        numDays = isLeap(year)? 29:28;
        break;
    default:
        numDays = 0;
    break;
        }
    return numDays;
  }//method

 public static boolean isLeap(int year){
    if(((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
  }


 public static int getDayofTheWeek(int day, int month, int year){

    int y = year - (14-month)/12;
    int x = y+y/4 - y/100 + y/400;
    int m = month + 12 * ((14-month)/12) -2;
    int d = (day + x + (31*m)/12)%7;
    return d;

  }//method

 }//class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to using the day of the week is what messes up your printed data. In this example I'm using a temporary array to save one row of days (a.k.a. one printed line). Once the 7th day of a week is stored in the array, we print the whole week. This also happens when the last day of the month is reached.

```
 for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
        outputFile.println("\n          " + getMonthName(month));
        outputFile.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
        int numDays = getNumberofDays(month, year);

        int[] week = new int[7];
        for (int day = 1; day <= numDays; day++) {
            int dayWeek = getDayofTheWeek(day, month, year);
            week[dayWeek] = day;

            // did we reach the 7th day of the week or the last day of the month?
            if ((dayWeek + 1) % 7 == 0 || day == numDays) {
                // print the week as one row
                for (int d : week) {
                    // don't print 0 values
                    outputFile.printf("%3s ", d == 0 ? "" : d);
                }
                outputFile.println("");
                // reset the array to store a new row in the next loop iteration
                week = new int[7];
            }
        }
        outputFile.println("");
    }
```